# Facebook: How to tag friend on video via taggable_id?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to upload video on fb timeline and tag user's friends on it. Uploading is pretty simple. I add binary data of video:

```
someUrlForm.AddBinaryData("file", binaryData, fileName, "multipart/form-data");
```

and call Graph API request that gives me uploaded video id:

```
https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?title={0}&description={1}&access_token={2}
```

[Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/) suggests to use "mention" in video description like `@[main_user_id]` but so I can't tag people who doesn't have my app. Now `/me/friends` API is used for retrieving "main" (not taggable) id's of users who add the application.

The only way I guess is to use `actions` as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#tags). It has `tags` field for `taggable_id`. Problem is I want to tag not a self-hosted `object` form link but existing video on timeline.

Maybe I need to create custom action to upload video with tags?

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API Video object doc specifies support only for page mentioning of the form @[page-id], and that is subject to review.